# How can I make a position:fixed image its own line/block?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu button image placed below a logo div, and position:fixed to the right side of the viewport. My body text, however, also starts directly below the logo div, so if it's a large paragraph of text, it runs behind the image.

How can I get the fixed-position image to act as its own line/force a line break/work with display: block/otherwise push the text down so the text starts below the image?

I've tried using display: block with the image or image div, but I may be styling it wrong. Also, I clearly have no clue what I'm doing, so sorry about the mess!

```
<head><style>
    img.logo {
    height: 3em;
    max-width: 80%;
    width: auto;
    padding: .5em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}

div.menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;}

.menu img {
    position: fixed;
    right: .5em;
    padding: .5em;}
</style></head>

<html>
    <img class="logo" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo-white.svg">
    <div class="menu">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95732802/menu.svg">
    </div>

    I'm some text!
</html>
```

And fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ylmk/B5LEk/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` is taken out of the document flow and thus setting its `display` property to `block` won't do anything.

If you know the height of the image, I would simply using a `margin` or padding, e.g.:

```
header {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Or:

```
header {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Or, if you just have a sequence of `<p>` elements after `<header>`:

```
header + p { /* if you have a p after it */
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Adjusting the padding or margin of the logo just pushes the menu image down with the text. I assume that's because the button is only fixed right, not top, but I'd like to avoid fixing it to the top. Am I misreading or misapplying your solution?

Comment: I was responding to the fiddle. For your inline answer, you would want to add a `height` or `margin-bottom` to the `.menu`. Let me know if that's the appropriate answer and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I was misapplying--I was padding the logo, assuming that the padding would bleed over the fixed image, when you meant to pad the entire header element. That works! I may try a different approach later that avoids the :fixed, but this is great for now.